# SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '{'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Here is the snapshot of error occurring, I don't know what I am doing wrong:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fluub.png)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    String query = "INSERT INTO STOCK_IN { SIN_No., PO_NO., Product_ID, Received_Date, Quantity } VALUES ('"+textBox1.Text+ "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')";

    SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query , con);
    SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY");
}
```

Comment: What you are doing wrong is clearly using invalid SQL syntax. `{` is not used in SQL, so why do you expect that to work?

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: I tried using '(' but still there is error.

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            String query = "INSERT INTO STOCK_IN (SIN_No.,PO_NO.,Product_ID,Recieved_Date,Quantity) VALUES ('"+ textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')";
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query , con);
            SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY");
        }

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

Answer (score 2):

The curly brackets are incorrect syntax. Also try something like this to handle this insert and catch errors. Also there is a trailing period after SIN_NO and I don't know if that is part of your column name or a typo.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String query = "INSERT INTO STOCK_IN(SIN_No., PO_NO., Product_ID, Received_Date, Quantity) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5)";

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@val1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
            //Then the same for 2, 3, 4, 5

            sda = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) 
    {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
    }
    finally 
    { 
         con.Close(); 
         MessageBox.Show("DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using '(' but still there is error.     
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { con.Open(); String query = "INSERT INTO STOCK_IN (SIN_No.,PO_NO.,Product_ID,Recieved_Date,Quantity) VALUES ('"+ textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')"; SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query , con); SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); con.Close(); MessageBox.Show("DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY"); }
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

Comment: The answer below mine is probably one of your other issues. If those '.' are part of your column names and not typos you should put the names in [] e.g. [SIN_No.], [PO_NO.]. Generally I would avoid adding special characters to my table designs unless you have a good reason to have them.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** change the `{}` to `()`.

**Step 2:** The problem is your column names have special characters. Use `[ ]` to specify the column name which contains the special character (like dot). Try this; it will solve your problem.

```
 INSERT INTO STOCK_IN ([SIN_No.],[PO_NO.], Product_ID, Received_Date, Quantity)
 VALUES ('"+ textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" +textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')
```

Comment: You **should REALLY** rather use a **parametrized query** instead of suggestion this code which is still **highly vulnerable** to SQL injection - the #1 exploit on the whole web .......

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the `{` to `(` same with the closing one. So `INSERT INTO STOCK_IN (` and close it with `)` rather than `}`.

```
INSERT INTO STOCK_IN( SIN_No., PO_NO., Product_ID, Received_Date, Quantity)
```

Comment: We do not answer typo questions, we close and delete them.

Comment: I tried using '(' but still there is error. private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { con.Open(); String query = "INSERT INTO STOCK_IN (SIN_No.,PO_NO.,Product_ID,Recieved_Date,Quantity) VALUES ('"+ textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')"; SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query , con); SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); con.Close(); MessageBox.Show("DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY"); } System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'